# Is it possible to stream images from resources.resx?

Tags: c#, combobox, picturebox, resx

I got about 100 images loaded in resx and was wondering if it was possible to add them to a stream and if it is how to do it.

My idea is this:

I got a combobox and from selecting an item from the combobox (same names as the images) it should load an image from resx to a picturebox.

I tried this example:

```
string SelectedComboboxItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(SelectedComboboxItem));
```

Which does not work since it can not convert object to system.drawing.image, same with .GetString & .GetType.

Or if there is any other way to do this then it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must cast object to your image type. Like so:

```
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("RowNameInResourceFile"));
```

For more examples look at [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963f81yd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Holy Moly! It worked! Tried to figure it out for several Days.. the closest I got was using the following
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)BitMap etc etc.. (or the other way around)
But it Always gave Null..
I Love you! Thanks!

Comment: @Xakzi Good to hear :)